# PC goes black screen & unresponsive after a while

Tags: 20.04, power-management, monitor, idle

I have a clean and fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04 along with the most recent GNOME desktop. Although I have set in energy settings that the screen should never go off, it does so, and in addition, none of the keys on the keyboard I might press will wake it up, nor does mouse movement. All I can do is press the PCs power button, which will wake up the PC.

However, this does not work when I just start the PC and don't log in. In this case, still at the login screen, the screen also goes off after a while, but triggering the PC's power button will instead now power off the PC.

How can I completely disable this feature, so that the PC never goes to sleep?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I am using a monitor with USB hub, where the mouse & keyboard is connected. Maybe this is an issue. I am pretty sure, however, that on Windows the mouse/keyboard stay responsive, even after the monitor goes dark.